# PHPDOMDocument cannot output chinese characters after saveHTMLFile();

Tags: php

I first load my HTML file, the html file already has  .
$DOM = new DOMDocument();

$DOM->loadHTMLFile($file);

after manipulating with the document, I save the HTML file by $DOM->saveHTMLFile($file);

However the chinese characters in the document changed to code like &#29872

may I know how to fix that?

Comment: I think it's a font problem are you sure your font support this carracters ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty weird one, and I can't fully explain why this happens, but I do know how to work around it. Basically you need to pass the root node to [saveHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php), this will prevent the entity encoding.

```
<?php
$html = <<<END
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hant">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>世界級效能</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>分析和縱向擴充軟體定義部署提供出色</p>
</body>
</html>
END;


$DOM = new DOMDocument();

$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$outDefaultFile = 'zh_save.html';
$outXpathFile = 'zh_save_xpath.html';

//Save out default HTML file - will have characters encoded to HTML entities
$DOM->saveHTMLFile($outDefaultFile);

// Set up XPATH and get root node
$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$res = $xpath->query('/')->item(0);

// Write out root node to HTML file, will not encode entities
file_put_contents($outXpathFile, $DOM->saveHTML($res));
```

Answer (score 0):

SaveHTMLFile Creates an HTML document from the DOM representation. This function is usually called after building a new dom document from scratch at output file. All Chinese alphabet have Unicode for display it in HTML. HTML parsing parse it to Unicode.

But SaveHTML consider pass parameter as string . And does not parse it to Unicode. In short. "

string

" SaveHTML save string of files.

SaveHTMLFile parse it to HTML encode and then save in HTML encoded string.